# vscode laguage server extension script stucked in production

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

on production, it takes almost ten minute to get the log `scaning file done` done. And there is no problem when I debug this vscode extension. I wonder why it get stucked. Thanks.

the origin project is here:
https://github.com/mrmlnc/vscode-less

```
    stream.on('file', (stat) => {
        const entry = makeEntryFile(stat.path, stat.ctime);
        // Return Cache if it exists and not outdated
        const cached = cache.get(entry.filepath);
        if (cached && cached.ctime.getTime() >= entry.ctime.getTime()) {
            listOfPromises.push(cached);
            return;
        }
        listOfPromises.push(makeSymbolsForDocument(cache, entry, settings));
    });
    stream.on('error', (err) => {
        if (settings.showErrors) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
    stream.on('end', () => __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
        let projectSymbols = [];
        let importedSymbols = [];
        try {
            projectSymbols = yield Promise.all(listOfPromises);
            // on production, it takes almost ten minute to get the log done.
            (0, server_1.getConnection)().console.log('scaning file done')

            if (settings.scanImportedFiles) {
                importedSymbols = yield scannerImportedFiles(cache, projectSymbols, settings);
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            if (settings.showErrors) {
                reject(err);
            }
        }
        resolve(projectSymbols.concat(importedSymbols));
    }));



function makeSymbolsForDocument(cache, entry, settings) {
  return (0, fs_1.readFile)(entry.filepath).then((data) => {
    if (cache.keys().length % 50 == 0) {
        (0, server_1.getConnection)().console.log('scaning file ' + entry.filepath)
    }

    const doc = vscode_languageserver_1.TextDocument.create(entry.filepath, 'less', 1, data);
    const { symbols } = (0, parser_1.parseDocument)(doc, null, settings);
    symbols.ctime = entry.ctime;
    cache.set(entry.filepath, symbols);
    return symbols;
  });
}
```

the log in console:

```
scaning file businessapplication/invoice/splitInvoiceModal.less

scaning file platform/flow/workflowdrawing/ruletabs/designatedPosts.less

scaning file platform/expenseclaim/editor/component/expenseRecord/compositeAmount.less

scaning file done
```

vscode discussion link(you could get the extension vsix file here):
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/325

Comment: Why do you scan files with an extension in production?

Comment: @Konrad Thanks for reply. Because it needs to get all symbols of all less files in workspace for offering Hover/Completion functionality. The `scan&parse` works fine when I debug the extension